# Why there are two instances of SQL Server Management Studio and SQL Server 2017 Express?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017, ssms-2016, ssms-2017

I have recently installed SSMS 17 and SQL Server from this link: [SSM Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms),
and I also installed SQL Server Express from the official site.

As on SSMS download page there are two downloads available SSM Studio 17.6 and 17.6 upgraded packages so I installed both. And now I am confused a bit because in SSMS I see two database engines `SQLEXPRESS` and `SQLEXPRESS01` although it only connects to RAO-HAMMAS-PC as you can see here in the screenshot:

[image: SSMS Database Engines Image]

Also I see two instances of SSMS 17.6 in programs and features window - see this screenshot

[image: SSMS installed image]

and both have same version but different size. Please help me if I have duplicate installed SSMS ?

And just one more thing SQL Server keeps running in background even if I am not using it. So can I stop it somehow? And only use it when I am developing?

Comment: I think you're mixing up things. Those instances are databases. SSMS is just to tool to connect to them.

Comment: @JamesZ hi :) okey but that tool is showing two times in programs and features plus what's that SQLEXPRESS and SQLEXPRESS1 ? and ssms does not connect to these but connects to RAO-HAMMAS-PC or is it all just fine ?

Comment: @JamesZ no, I think those are 3 instances. And the only reason there would be 3 showing is if you have 3 instances running. How many show in the configuration manager?

Comment: Visual Studio often installs a SQL express instance alongside (or at least it used to). Have you installed 2 versions of VS? That could unexpectedly cause this.

Comment: no i installed only one visual studio community 17 from official source ! but yeah i did install SSMS 2 ..as two downloads are available on there page as i mentioned in question with link !

Comment: @MikeD. SSM Studio 17.6 and 17.6 upgraded